# The last vertical line is broken ... How do I leave it as a single line?

Tags: tables, line-breaking, grids, vertical

I tried to make a representation of a list of data structure as in the example below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

        \begin{figure}[htb]
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{
                    |c|ccc|
            } \cline{1-2}  \cline{4-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Index 1}}
                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Index 2}}
                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{...}}
                & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Index N}}
                \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-4}
                \\[-1ex]
                % -- Index 1
                \begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline
                    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{My Data Structure}\\ \hline
                    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}First\\Field\end{tabular} &
                    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Second\\Field\end{tabular} \\
                    \hline
                \end{tabular} &

                % -- Index 2
                \begin{tabular}{|c|c} \hline
                    \multicolumn{2}{|c}{My Data Struct...}\\ \hline
                    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}First\\Field\end{tabular} &
                    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Sec..\\Fie...\end{tabular} \\
                    \hline
                \end{tabular} &

                % -- Gap ...
                \begin{tabular}{c}
                    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{...}}\\
                    \textbf{...} \\
                \end{tabular} &

                % -- Index N
                \begin{tabular}{c|c|} \hline
                    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{...ata Structure}\\ \hline
                    \begin{tabular}[r]{@{}l@{}}...rst\\...ield\end{tabular}
                    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Second\\Field\end{tabular} \\      \hline
                \end{tabular} \\[4ex]
                \cline{1-2}  \cline{4-4}
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
        \caption{List of Data Structure.}
        \label{fig:control_response_list}
        \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It was almost the way I would like to present, if not for the space on the last vertical line of the grid, as shown in the figure.

[image]

How can I do to have the last full vertical line?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the definition of the individual cells in the second row of your outer tabular (the one which you make shorter by `\\[-1ex]`). LaTeX will then only set the first column's cell (which is empty) and put the vertical bar after it, but skip the processing of the remaining cells in that row. Thus the vertical bar after the last column won't be printed.

The solution is to simply add all column separators for the second row:

```
\\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-4}
& & &
\\[-1ex]
```

will correctly print

[image]